# Add description to google cloud endpoints variables

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints

How do I add a description string to google cloud endpoint variables so that it's visible in google's API explorer?
I was able to add a description to methods using comments """ """. For example:

```
@endpoints.method(LocationRequestMessage, LocationResponseMessage, path='location', http_method='POST',
                  name='location.create')
def location_create(self, request):
    """
    Creates a location
    """
```

Here is an example of what I do want to achieve:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.acl.insert

Input fields:

calendarId--> **Calendar identifier**.

Request body:

scope--> **The scope of the rule**

Where do I have to add the bold description text to get it displayed?

Answer (score 1):

The comments are defined in the discovery files (APPLICATION-NAME-rest.discovery).

From the [Google APIs Discovery Service](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis):

```
"methods": {
    (key): {
      "id": string,
      "path": string,
      "httpMethod": string,
      "description": string,
      "parameters": {
        (key): {
          "id": string,
          "type": string,
          "$ref": string,
          "description": string,
          "default": string,
          "required": boolean,
          "format": string,
          "pattern": string,
```

you can see there are fields for "description". Currently it seems that `endpoints.sh get-discovery` does not fetch the code comments and fill these descriptions. But you can modify the .discovery files by yourself and deploy to appengine.

Comment: Where whould "endpoints.sh get-discovery" fetch the code comments from? I did try to add it to the Message definition (id = messages.IntegerField(1, description='Test')), but it didn't work: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'description'. Any other ideas?

Comment: For Javascript and other dynamic languages the discovery document is dynamically generated by Google Cloud endpoints at runtime and you can't replace its URL with your overwritten file.